# Having trouble with file I/O and string arrays

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

The file I'm reading from just has names separated by a line. What happens is the program tries to print the contents of `line_array`, and it will print out about 20 of the last line in the txt file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE* fp;

int main(){

    char* line;
    const char* line_array[255];
    int i= 0;
    int b =0;
    fp = fopen("noob.txt","r");

    while(fgets(line,255,fp)){
        line_array[i]=line;
        printf("%s",line);
        printf("%s",line_array[i]);
        i++;
    }

    for(;b<i;b++){
        printf("%s",line_array[b]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) `char* line;` --> `char line[255];` 2) `line_array[i]=line;` --> `line_array[i]=strdup(line);`//strdup in <string.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue, in your code,

```
while(fgets(line,255,fp))
```

`line` is used uninitialized. There is no memory allocated to `line`. It invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Then, you did not check for the success of `fopen()` before using the returned file pointer. Again, possible UB.

And finally, by saying

```
 line_array[i]=line;
```

what you did is to store the `line` itself to all the occurrences of `line_array[n]`, so for the later `printf()` loop, the latest content of `line` is being printed over and over again.

*Solution(s):*

- Allocate memory to `line` or use a fixed length-array.
- Check for the success of `fopen()`before using the returned pointer.
- Allocate memory to each `line_array[n]` and use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) to copy the content. Ottherwise, you can directly use [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup), too.